# VueJS display grouped array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, lodash

I'm fetching a list of countries from the API and I want to display them in groups by subregion (continent). Like that:

[image]

API gives me a response which is an array of objects (countries) and for each object there is a key called 'subregion' - I want to group by that key.
I use lodash for grouping, but maybe there is a Vue method I'm not familiar with.
My JS code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    countries: null,
  },

  created: function () {
    this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var self = this;
      xhr.open('GET', apiURL);
      xhr.onload = function() {
        var countryList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        self.countries = _.groupBy(countryList, "subregion");
      };
      xhr.send();
    },
  },
});
```

And HTML:

```
<li v-for="country in countries">
        {{ country.name }} (+{{ country.callingCodes[0] }})
</li>
```

How can I achieve what's in the picture?

Comment: VueJS does not have helper methods like that for grouping of data: it is not designed to do that. It simply provides a framework for MVVC data binding. Can you share an example of the JSON response you get?

Comment: I am not sure what is the actual question here.

Comment: @Terry sure, this is the exact response https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Comment: What does your current code output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've correctly grouped countries by their subregion using lodash with the following code.

```
_.groupBy(countryList, "subregion")
```

This has given you an object whose keys are names of subregions, and the values are arrays of objects with such subregion.

So your mistake is that you expect a value in `countries` to contain `name`. Instead, it contains an *array* of objects with `name`s.

You need two for-loops for this.

Here's a vanilla implementation. Here's [a bin](http://jsbin.com/baqofijino/edit?js,console), too.

```
fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => {
    const grouped = _.groupBy(data, 'subregion')
    const listOfSubregions = Object.keys(grouped)

    listOfSubregions.forEach(key => {
      console.log(' =========== ' + key + ' =========== ')
      const countriesInThisSubregion = grouped[key]
      countriesInThisSubregion.forEach(country => {
        console.log(country.name + ' ' + country.callingCodes[0])
      })
    })
  })
```

With Vue, you'd have something like the following (not tested, but should be super-easy to deduce based on the above code).

```
<li v-for="subregion in subregions">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="country of subregion">
        {{ country.name }} ({{ country.callingCodes[0] }})
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: After thinking about it a bit, I came to the same conclusion. Thanks for help!

Comment: How can you `groupBy` with 2 keys ?