# javascript slice object for paging?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, grouping, javascript-objects

I use vue.js to display a grouped list of objects.
So I initially have an array like

```
   var array = [{region: 'region1', parent_region: 'parent_region'}]
```

I use a simple
`var groupedObject = _.groupBy(array, "parent_region")`
 to get a grouped object by the parent region.

Now, I want to display this grouped object in a nested table, **with a paging interface**. How can I page/slice a javascript object? i.e displaying keys between two indexes as I could do with the array.
The problem is that javascript object cannot be accessed by index nor they are ordered.
Is there any other javascript struct for this purpose?

Comment: You should start with what your groupedObject looks like and then provide a working example (if you can) of what you've tried as a snippet

Comment: Why can't you just iterate the array? Show code.

Comment: Because the array is not grouped, So I can't print it in a nested table with vue.js. I don't have a working javascript code yet, this is what I want to achieve. My question is very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906741/vuejs-display-grouped-array-of-objects , But here I need paging as well

Comment: Just convert the grouped object to an array of `{ parent_region: '...', regions: [...] }` objects.